# Passing data to broadcast receiver using sendTextMessage()

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, sms

How to pass data to broadcast receiver when using `sendTextMessage()`
I have used `intent.putExtra("key","value");` and when the `onReceive` function called the value of `intent.getStringExtra("key")` is **null**.

What I should do? Please help.

NOTE: when used `sendBroadcast(new Intent(smsSent).putExtra("key","value"));` the **value was passed**.

Activity.java

```
void send_sms(){
String smsSent = "SMS_SENT";
String smsDelivered = "SMS_DELIVERED";
PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
new Intent(smsSent).putExtra("key1", "value1"), 0);
PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
new Intent(smsDelivered).putExtra("key2", "value2"), 0);

SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage("5556", null, "hi", sentPI, deliveredPI);
}
```

MyReceiver.java

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

 Log.i("my receiver"," "+intent.getAction());// this statement works fine
 Log.i("my receiver"," "+intent.getStringExtra("key1"));// null is returned
}
```

manifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="SMS_SENT" />
    <action android:name="SMS_DELIVERED" /> 
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I think the problem could be, that you didn't mention your package.
try this in your manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="your.package.name.SMS_DELIVERED" />
</intent-filter>
```

and this in your code:

```
String smsDelivered = "your.package.name.SMS_DELIVERED";
```

replace `your.package.name` with your package name!
hope that helps :)

Comment: im sorry, check the edit question, it's not a typing error. thanx

Comment: check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013856/how-to-make-a-broadcast-receiver-catch-menu-volume-home-button-clic) my be you find something.